# how to configure X-Frame-Option in app.yaml

Tags: angularjs, python-2.7, google-app-engine

I want to set X-Frame-Option to my application so that it will be applicable for all js files and html files. Please provide syntax how to configure in app.yaml. Application uses "google app engine" and backend code is in "python".

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appref#handlers_http_headers),

> you can set HTTP headers for responses of your static file or
>   directory handlers. If you need to set HTTP headers in your script
>   handlers, you should instead do that in your app's code.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> handlers:
> - url: /images
>   static_dir: static/images
>   http_headers:
>     X-Foo-Header: foo
>     X-Bar-Header: bar value
> ```